# How to code a synchronous wrapper for jquery ajax functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronous

I'm converting synchronous ajax calls to asynchronous because synchronous calls are no longer supported in most browsers.  Since my code is filled with synchronous (and dynamic) ajax calls (to client-side functions) where the code absolutely cannot continue until the call is complete, I'm hoping I can do something like replacing `synchronousAjaxFunction();` with `waitForCompletion(asynchronousAjaxFunction());` but haven't found any solutions that allow this to work without turning my code inside-out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Inside a Module, with top-level `await`, instead of `waitForCompletion(asynchronousAjaxFunction());` you would simply use: `await asynchronousAjaxFunction(); // Other code that uses some data...` ... but read the answer below.

Comment: "*synchronous calls are no longer supported in most browsers*" - really? I'm pretty sure they're still supported, just deprecated and despised.

Comment: "*I'm hoping I can do something like `waitForCompletion`*" - no, this is completely impossible. You really should rewrite your code to be asynchronous and *wait* for the ajax result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, make sure to remove any `async: false,` from your jQuery scripts, since synchronous XHR can hang the main thread leading to unresponsive applications.

Then, if you're using a jQuery version lower then 3.0 create a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) wrapper for `$.ajax` like:

```js
// For jQuery v. < 3.0. jQuery v. 3.0+ implement already A* Promises.
// Use $ajaxP instead of $.ajax
const $ajaxP = (opts) => new Promise((res, rej) => $.ajax(opts).done(res).fail(rej));
```

### Using Modules and *top-level await*

One way to do it would be by using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) as [**top-level await**](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) (without needing to define an `async` wrapper function) inside a [**module**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) - but such is considered **bad practice** since it's hard to reason about your program flow. If [not used correctly](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221) could lead to undesired results. Without properly understanding all the implications you should not per-se rewrite AJAX calls to make them *"synchronous"-but-good*.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="module">
console.log("Some code before...");

const data = await $.ajax({url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"});

console.log(data);
console.log("Some code that uses data...");

</script>
```

### Using Promise based function

What you can do instead is to slightly rewrite your code to make it look and behave like it's *synchronous*, by using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and wrapping the crucial synchronous code into [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Here's a starting synchronous sample code we need to rewrite into a better, Promise-based approach:

```js
// !!! WARNING !!! 
// This a bad example that we need to rewrite
// from async:false AJAX call to a better, Promises based approach!

let data;

console.log("Some code before...");

$.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
    async: false,
}).done((response) => {
  data = response;
}).fail(console.error);
  
console.log(data);
console.log("Some code that uses data...");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can use `$ajaxP` in a similar fashion, just make sure to use `async` and `await` in your functions:

```js
const someFunction = async () => { // Make your function async
  
  console.log("Some code before...");

  const data = await $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  });
  
  console.log(data);
  console.log("Some code that uses data...");
};

someFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For better error handling use a `try/catch` block:

```js
const someFunction = async () => { // Make your function async
  
  let data;
  
  console.log("Some code before...");

  try {
    data = await $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    // Do something about the error and data  
  }
  
  console.log(data);
  console.log("Some code that uses data...");
};

someFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If needed you can also use `$ajaxP` with [Promise.prototype.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

```js
$.ajax({url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"})
  .then((data) => {
    console.log("Some code before...");
    console.log(data)
    console.log("Some code that uses data...");
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or just the default jQuery way:

```js
$.ajax({url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"})
  .done((data) => {
    console.log("Some code before...");
    console.log(data)
    console.log("Some code that uses data...");
  })
  .fail(console.error);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### You don't need jQuery

If you have time and plan to get rid of jQuery, as a heads-up you can use JavaScript's [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead:

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {/* options here */})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
  
    console.log("Some code before...");
    
    console.log(data)
    console.log("Some code that uses data...");
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

or using async/await:

```js
console.log("Some code before");

(async () => {
  
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {/* options here */});
  const data = await res.json();
  
  console.log(data);
  console.log("Some code after that uses data");

})();

console.log("Some code after that does NOT uses data");
```

or as already mentioned, inside a **Module**, with **top-level await**:

```html
<script type="module">
console.log("Some code before");

const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {/* options here */});
const data = await res.json();
  
console.log(data);
console.log("Some code after that uses data");
</script>
```

Comment: "*make it look and behave like it's synchronous*" - an `async` function does not behave synchronously. It executes code sequentially, but it's still asynchronous and does risk race conditions.

Comment: "*create a Promise wrapper for `$.ajax`*" - no need for the `new Promise` constructor. jQuery deferreds are thenable since 1.7-something, and all you need is `Promise.resolve($.ajax(opts))`. If you `await` it, you don't even need that.

Comment: @Bergi Exactly. All of this is stated in the answer. Regarding the *wrapper* both in text and even in code comments and in the code itself. Regarding await - yes. Further code execution is paused, not in the main thread but in the block or module regardless. Therefore the *"behave like it's synchronous"*. Also that a *rewrite* is needed - seems pretty obvious from the posted answer.